# Get the returned url of an ajax call with a browser extension

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, browser, browser-extension

What I'd like to do is make an ajax request to some url whose server I don't have access to.  When the ajax call returns I'd like to get the url of the page I returned from.  So, if I make an ajax call to example.com and I get redirected to example2.com, I'd like to get the url for example2.com.  I know, after reading some similar posts, that the browser follows the requests transparently and doesn't return the url.

However I was wondering if that was because those ajax requests were originating in the page.  If I were to originate my ajax request in the browser via some browser extension would it be possible to get the returned url?

If this is not possible, are there alternative ways of going about this?  I thought that iframes might work- make an iframe whose source is the target url and see if it gets redirected.  However, I noticed that some websites don't act normally, out of security protocol, inside of an iframe, so this doesn't seem like the best solution.  Another thought was to use cURL, which I'd really like to not have to do. Is what I'm trying to do even possible in cURL?

Thanks for the help.